# Open Primefaces dialog and Process Full JSF Lifecycle

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm doing a `<p:commandLink value="#{bundle['registered.home.search.TEXT']}" onclick="webSearchDlg.show();"></p:commandLink>` in order to show the below dialog.  The p:outputPanel id="searchPnl" always renders after its initially rendered.  It never disappears even though the dialogs `closeListener="#{dreamSearch.close}" onCloseUpdate="searchTxtPnl,searchPnl"` is executed.  When I open the dialog after closing it, the panelGrid appears and the `<p:inputText id="searchText">` displays the previous value that I tried to clear in the below closeListener method.  Any ideas...code below...

```
<p:dialog header="#{bundle['dreamSearch.HEADER']}"
    widgetVar="webSearchDlg" modal="true" styleClass="dialog dialog2"
    draggable="false" resizable="false" showEffect="fade"
    hideEffect="fade" closeListener="#{dreamSearch.close}" onCloseUpdate="searchTxtPnl,searchPnl">
    <div class="dialog-top-reg"></div>
    <div class="dialog-middle-reg">
        <div class="close-button">
            <h:form>
                <p:commandButton onclick="webSearchDlg.hide()" />
            </h:form>
        </div>
        <h:form class="dialog-content dialog-content2"
            binding="#{dreamSearch.dreamSearchFrm}">
            <h1 class="dream-search">
                <h:outputText value="#{bundle['dreamSearch.HEADER']}" />
            </h1>
            <p class="dream-search">
                <h:outputText value="#{bundle['dreamSearch.SUBHEADER']}" />
            </p>
            <div class="dream-search-wrap">
                <fieldset>
                <p:outputPanel id="searchTxtPnl">
                    <p:inputText id="searchText" value="#{dreamSearchBean.searchText}"/>
                </p:outputPanel>
                    <p:commandButton styleClass="form-btn1"
                        value="#{bundle['dreamSearch.search.button.TEXT']}" onclick="webImageSearch()"/>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
            <p:remoteCommand name="webImageSearch" process="searchText, @this" actionListener="#{dreamSearch.search}" update="searchPnl"/>
            <p:outputPanel id="searchPnl" styleClass="data-grid-wrap">
                <h:outputText value="#{bundle['dreamSearch.imageResults.TEXT']}" rendered="#{dreamSearchBean.shouldRender}"/>
                <p:dataGrid var="img" value="#{dreamSearchBean.images}" columns="5"
                    rows="10" paginator="true" effect="true"
                    paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                    rowsPerPageTemplate="10,15,20" paginatorPosition="bottom" rendered="#{dreamSearchBean.shouldRender}">
                    <p:column>
                        <h:panelGrid columns="1" style="width:100%">
                            <p:graphicImage value="#{img}" width="40" height="50" />
                        </h:panelGrid>
                    </p:column>
                </p:dataGrid>
            </p:outputPanel>
        </h:form>
    </div>
    <div class="dialog-bottom-reg"></div>
</p:dialog>


@Named
@Scope("request")
public class DreamSearch extends BaseAction {
    @Inject
    DreamService dreamService;
    @Inject
    ImageSearchService flickrSearchImpl;
    @Inject
    private DreamSearchBean dreamSearchBean;
    private UIForm dreamSearchFrm;


    public void init(){
        if (!FacesUtils.isPostback()) {
            dreamSearchBean.setShouldRender(false);
            dreamSearchBean.setSearchText(null);
        }
    }

    public void setDreamSearchFrm(UIForm dreamSearchFrm) {
        this.dreamSearchFrm = dreamSearchFrm;
        init();
    }

    public void search(ActionEvent e){
        try {

            if(dreamSearchBean.getSearchText() != null && !dreamSearchBean.getSearchText().isEmpty()){
                List<String> searchResults = flickrSearchImpl.searchByKeyWord(dreamSearchBean.getSearchText());
                dreamSearchBean.setImages(searchResults);
                dreamSearchBean.setShouldRender(true);
            }else{
                dreamSearchBean.setShouldRender(false);
            }

        } catch (Exception e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void close(CloseEvent e){
        dreamSearchBean.setShouldRender(false);
        dreamSearchBean.setSearchText(null);
    }

    public UIForm getDreamSearchFrm() {
        return dreamSearchFrm;
    }
}

    @Named
@Scope("session")
public class DreamSearchBean extends BaseSessionBean {
    private List<String> images;
    private String searchText;
    private boolean shouldRender;



    public String getSearchText() {
        return searchText;
    }

    public void setSearchText(String searchText) {
        this.searchText = searchText;
    }

    public boolean isShouldRender() {
        return shouldRender;
    }

    public void setShouldRender(boolean shouldRender) {
        this.shouldRender = shouldRender;
    }

    public List<String> getImages() {
        return images;
    }

    public void setImages(List<String> images) {
        this.images = images;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't really know what the reason for this behavior is, but you could try the following:

For the `<p:outputPanel id="searchPnl">`: try to set the rendered tag on the panel and not on the `h:outputText` and `p:dataGrid`.

For the searchText try to update the `<p:outputPanel id="searchTxtPnl">` instead of the `h:inputText`.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that the scope of your bean is request.  If your doing ajax updates this really needs to be a ViewScoped bean with the JSF @ManagedBean and @ViewScoped annotations.

Another thing: make sure your not updating the form where the dialog resides in.  This could have unwanted results.

Comment: I have session scoped beans for all my object data.  The request scoped beans just have the action and actionListener methods.  The request based beans have get an injected instance of the session scoped "data" bean. I guess with the new view scope I could combine the classes.  What do you think?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but yes I would consolidate them into a view scoped bean.  But remember CDI doesn't have a view scope, so you will have to use the JSF 2.0 annotations.